# Why is this simple express server running on two ports?

Tags: node.js, express, requestjs

I have simple node server, like so:

```
var express = require('express');  
var request = require('request');
var apiServerHost = "http://<IP address>:3000/api#!/"


var app = express();  
app.use('/', function(req, res) {  
  var url = apiServerHost + req.url;
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3001);
```

I run it with `node server.js`. Then in browser both port `3001` and `3000` have access to the server. If I replace 3001 with anything else, it will run on `3000` and the something else.

Why is that?

Comment: If you're saying that the browser can access port 3000 no matter what port you put this simple node server on, then you must either have some other server process that is listening to 3000 or you have some sort of port forwarding configured that makes it appear something is listening on port 3000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have another instance running (in the background, in other terminal) and listening on port 3000.

To see what ports are open and by which process, run:

```
netstat -ltnp
```

To see what processes are running, run:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

or:

```
ps aux | grep server.js
```

Try shutting the program down and make sure nothing listens on port 3001 and then try to access port 3000.

Comment: Somehow there was a hidden process running the same server from different directory (before I moved it), so it was invisible. It works now, thanks!